# Why the pearson correlation p-value doesn't fully correspond to CI in R?

Tags: r, correlation, pearson-r

Calculating Pearson correlation using the `cor.test()` function in R, I found that the p-value does not necessarily correspond to the CI:

```
# reproducible example
# generate the data
set.seed(123)
N <- 200
X <- rnorm(N)
a <- 0.2
b <- 0.8
sigma <- 4
eps <- rnorm(N, 0, sigma)
Y <- a + b * X + eps
Y[1] <- 23.70932 # change a bit

cor.test(X, Y)
```

The resultant CI says the correlation is significant, while the p-value says otherwise:

```
t = 1.9717, df = 198, p-value = 0.05004
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.00002440203 0.27226422569
sample estimates:
      cor 
0.1387649
```

The difference is small, but **still quite large to be explained as a numerical error**. This test does produce two-tailed test (for both the CI and the p-value) with the CI level of 0.95. Corresponding one-tailed test would be like this:

```
Y[1] <- 37.692
cor.test(X, Y, alternative = "greater")
```

with a similar problem. I tried to use the parameter `exact = TRUE`, but that's not related to the default calculation of Pearson correlation coefficient.

So, is this just a big imprecision (probably a bug, since the cor.test function doesn't provide any tolerance/epsilon parameter, which it should probably specify with this quite large imprecision?). Is the imprecision caused by not using an exact distribution of pearson coefficient, but just some approximations, that would yield slightly different results when calculating CI and p-value? Or is there some other principial problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nearly all such questions are answered in the help on the relevant functions.

From the help for `cor.test`:

> If `method` is `"pearson"`, the test statistic is based on Pearson's product moment correlation coefficient `cor(x, y)` and follows a t distribution with `length(x)-2` degrees of freedom if the samples follow independent normal distributions. If there are at least 4 complete pairs of observation, an asymptotic confidence interval is given based on Fisher's Z transform.

The CI based on Fisher's z will not exactly correspond to the result of the t-test.

The usual hypothesis tests rely on the distribution of the test statistic under the null. In this case, the null distribution for the test is based on the population correlation being zero. Under that circumstance, you get a t-test (under the assumptions), but when the population correlation is not zero you no longer have a t-distribution for the statistic, so the confidence interval isn't based on that. If an exact distribution were used for the CI (a calculation involving the hypergeometric function $_2F_1$, or a related series expansion), then it should correspond.

Comment: Hi @Glen_b, thanks for the answer! But, if the p-value of the $r$ can be calculated using t-test, this means that $r$ has t-distribution, doesn't it? And in that case, why isn't its CI calculated using t-distribution as well?

Comment: The null distribution for the test is based on the population correlation being zero. Under that circumstance, you get a t-test (under the assumptions), but when the population correlation is not zero you no longer have a t-distribution for the statistic, so the confidence interval isn't based on that. If an exact distribution were used for the CI, then it should correspond.

Comment: @tdy My apologies; I see now that I shouldn't have rejected your edit. I was blind to the change of font in the html help and should have copied the text version of help instead.

Comment: @Glen_b no worries, thanks for leaving a note

Comment: @Glen_b: how do we know that the normal distribution is a better approximation to the exact distribution than the t-distribution? I.e. I get that the test statistic doesn't follow a t-distribution anymore in the case of a CI -- but why is it more accurate to assume it follows a normal distribution?

Comment: We have a result that shows that the Fisher-transformed sample correlation is asymptotically normal. It may be that in small samples that some t-approximation is often better; to my knowledge we don't have a result that says so.

Comment: @monade There might be a small paper in finding a suitable t approximation and showing that it generally works better

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b! I found [this](https://journals.librarypublishing.arizona.edu/jmmss/article/id/764/) paper which compares test statistics for correlation CIs. It contains the following sentence on p.56, 3rd paragraph, "*...classical literature (e.g., Guilford, 1956) suggested using the value from the z table. Current literature commonly draws the value from a t table to correct for sample size.*" which sounds like it has been standard at some point to use t-values. And I understand the sentence "*But it is so simple to use t and t does provide a minor improvement*" on p. 62, 2nd paragraph, ...

Comment: ... as an indication that using $t$ for the computation of confidence bounds is slightly more accurate than $z$, though I find the authors' wording not 100% clear.

Comment: What I couldn't find so far is the exact sampling distribution of the z-transformed correlation coefficient. ChatGPT says the Fisher's z-transformed correlation coefficient approximately follows a Student's t-distribution with df = N - 3, but I couldn't independently confirm this and also it is still an approximation. The reason is that I'd like to plot the exact distribution against the normal to see the discrepancies... I'd be super thankful if you have a hint!

Comment: 1. Ask ChatGPT for a reference for the claim, then actually check the reference. After the first 100 times you see that it just makes stuff up, you might be convinced to stop using it. 2. It's possible to find the exact pdf of the correlation coefficient under bivariate normality; it's related to the hypergeometric function $_2F_1$ (e.g. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CorrelationCoefficientBivariateNormalDistribution.html). It should be possible to write an expression down for the density of  a z-transformed version of it, via $f_Y(y) = f_X\bigl(h(y)\bigr) \left| \frac{d h(y)}{d y} \right|$....

Comment: ctd ... (see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Functions_of_random_variables), assuming the density is what you seek. I'm not sure that's particularly useful on its own though.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks a lot for your input, much appreciated. I've got the exact pdf of the correlation coefficient already implemented and I wanted to compare it to the z-transformed version. For now I just simulated this pdf, which works fine, but an expression would be much easier and more accurate. I'm a bit surprise that this expression is so hard to find in the www!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "compare the exact distribution to the z-transformed version" (at least that appears to be what you're saying there); the z-transformed version has been transformed, via a non-linear transformation; you can't compare them directly. I thought the idea was to compare the normal approximation for the Fisher-z transformed correlation with the exact density of the z-transformed correlation (which I just described above how to compute), which comparison does make at least some sense. Do you now *not* want to make that comparison?

Comment: @Glen_b I indeed want to compare the exact distributions before and after z-transformation. The point is to demonstrate the whole purpose of this transformation: a skewed distribution *before* the transformation versus (approximate) normality *after* the transformation. I'm aware they live in different spaces, but I think this is still a meaningful demo.  I'm a bit lost though how to translate your recipe for the derivation of the transformed version into programming code.

Comment: As the formula at the wikipedia page says, there are two terms in the product; the first (the "$f_X$" term) is the density you have, but the argument to is no longer $r$; it's the inverse of the z-transform, $h=g^{-1}$. Since $z=\operatorname{arctanh}(r)$, that's now $r = \tanh(z)$ so in the $f$ you have, $r$ is replaced with $\tanh(z)$ everywhere. Then the last term is the Jacobian of the transformation; since $\tanh$ is monotonic increasing the $|.|$ is redundant, so that term is just the derivative of $\tanh(z)$, which is $\operatorname{sech}^2(z)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, that makes a lot of sense! I'll give it a shot tomorrow.

Comment: @Glen_b: [It works](https://postimg.cc/xNDjfRMD) - Thanks once again!

Comment: The display nicely shows the nearly constant spread (if I remember correctly the z-transform is asymptotically variance stabilizing and nearly-symmetrizing). However, keep in mind that a visual assessment of normality from just *looking* at the density may not be very accurate (non-normality tends to impact the tails in particular, where there's little visual difference).

Comment: @monade If I can some time I may move some of that information from comments up to the end of my answer. If I do that, would you mind if I used your image? (with appropriate credit, naturally). I imagine it might be useful to later readers.

Comment: @Glen_b sure! You may also use [this](https://postimg.cc/w344bXgD) version, which takes a bit less space.

Comment: I found it interesting that the modus of the z-transform is still a bit off the population value at low sample sizes (it's expected, but still nice to see in this demo).